# Angular pass parameter from Template to Controller and from Controller to service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-resource

I have a code that use Resources to create and list using APIRest, I need pass a Id from template to controller and from controller to service.

This is my code:

Template.html

```
<div class="industrialists" ng-app="cliConsApp">
    <ul class="table" ng-controller="industrialistCtrl" ng-init="init('{{ constructionPrivateInformationId }}')">
        <form name="myForm">
            <input type="text" id="userName" ng-model="industrialist.user" placeholder="User name"/>
            <input type="text" id="jobName" ng-model="industrialist.job" placeholder="Job name"/>
            <a ng-click="createNewUser()" class="btn btn-small btn-primary">create new user</a>
        </form>

        <li ng-repeat="industrial in industrialists">
            [[industrial.job.name]]
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

app.js

```
var cliConsApp = angular.module('cliConsApp',['uTrans', 'cliConsApp.controllers', 'cliConsApp.services' ]).
    config(function($interpolateProvider){
        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[').endSymbol(']]');
    }
);;
```

services.js

```
var services = angular.module('cliConsApp.services', ['ngResource']);

services.factory('IndustrialistsFactory', function ($resource) {
    return $resource(
        '/app_dev.php/api/v1/constructionprivateinformations/:id/industrialists',
        {id: '@id'},
        {
            query: { method: 'GET', isArray: true },
            create: { method: 'POST'}
        }
    )
});
```

controllers.js

```
var app = angular.module('cliConsApp.controllers', []);

app.controller('industrialistCtrl', ['$scope', 'IndustrialistsFactory',

    function ($scope, IndustrialistsFactory) {

        $scope.init = function (id) {

            $scope.id=id;
            $scope.industrialists= IndustrialistsFactory.query({},{id: $scope.id});

            $scope.createNewUser = function (id) {
                IndustrialistsFactory.create($scope.industrialist, {id: $scope.id});
                $scope.industrialists = IndustrialistsFactory.query({id: $scope.id});

            }
        }
}]);
```

I have the problem in CreateNewUser because service not recive id and url not is correct.

How I can do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a major problem with your code. You have declared the models not directly inside the controller but inside the init function. This limits their scope and breaks the expressions like `ng-click="createNewUser()"`. Move them out:

```
app.controller('industrialistCtrl', ['$scope', 'IndustrialistsFactory',
    function ($scope, IndustrialistsFactory) {
        $scope.id = "";

        $scope.industrialists = [];

        $scope.createNewUser = function (id) {
            // update the models here
        }

        $scope.init = function (id) {
            // update the models here
        }
}]);
```